# Do we need to define ngOnDestroy for subject in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

When using subject is it required to unsubscribe by using ngOnDestroy hook or it will be automatically unsubscribed by angular?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. Example: When subscribing to an `HttpClient` call you do not have to worry about unsubcribing. If you build your own subject and subscribe to it then you are responsible for everything in the life cycle as it is out of angulars control.

Comment: also, if you're only using a subject in your template with the | async pipe, angular will unsubscribe automatically for you when the component is destroyed

Comment: @Kaushal:  There are other ways as well, check `first()` and `take()` in RxJS doc for example to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 1):

You should to manually unsubscribe all the subscriptions in the `ngOnDestroy()` for best practices and to prevent memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

OnDestroy’s primary purpose, according to the Angular Docs is to perform “Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks. Called just before Angular destroys the directive/component.” . So you should manually call unsubscribe method in ngOnDestroy() to prevent memory leak.

here is a link to article regarding the same. You can have a look on it.
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/exploring-angular-lifecycle-hooks-ondestroy